# General term for upcasting and downcasting?

Tags: terminology, type-theory

Is there a more precise term than simply "casting"? "Casting" often includes for example `integer -> float` or `pointer -> unrelated pointer`; whereas I'm describing exclusively casting up or down the type hierarchy.

Comment: What's wrong with "upcasting" and "downcasting"?

Comment: if you're writing a paper, you can simply define your own term

Comment: I named a Rust trait that provided `upcast` and `downcast` methods "Cast" and wondered if there was a more appropriate name!